# Problems with download link in phonegap android pdf

Tags: pdf, cordova

Someone know how to download an file (pdf) using phonegap for android

I already looked a lot of tutorial but any of them work for me.

THank you.

Comment: did u checked [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer)

Comment: check this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577230/phonegap-save-image-from-url-into-device-photo-gallery/21579097#21579097

Comment: I'm trying to follow your post, but I getting confused, in which file the I need to save you code example ? I'm really need with phonegap

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make use of the FileTransfer object here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer.

With this, you will need to call the download method - passing in the file URI, destination and success/error callbacks.

I.e., if I want to download a PDF, you could do so as follows:

```
var win = function(r) {
    console.log("Should not be called.");
}

var fail = function(error) {
    // error.code == FileTransferError.ABORT_ERR
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
    console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
}

var ft = new FileTransfer();

ft.download(
    'http://www.mydomain.com/mypdfdoc.pdf',
    myURI, // you can obtain this via a window.requestFileSystem(...)
    function (fileEntry) {
        // do something with fileEntry
    },
    function (error) {
        // handle error appropriately
    });
```

Comment: I try to use this code in my index page but it did't work, the I have to somethin else