# PhoneGap File Transfer Error 1, where to write FileTransfers?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044197/download-file-and-store-them-locally-in-sdcard-using-phonegapbuild but that questions has never been answered.

About this app, I'm writing a little app that displays a bunch of pdf's, it's written using jquerymobile + phonegap and it's being build with the phonegap build service.

I realize that this function cannot work, since the root-Directory is not a valid place to write anything. But, I was unable to get the working directory of my application, nor was I able to figure out what exactly Error Code 1 meant using the documentation.

from config.xml:

```
 <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal" />

<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />


<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
```

And the build service tells me that these plugins have been sucessfully added.

Unpacking the apk and looking into the manifest also reveals that

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

was successfully added.

last but not least the phonegap library was successfully added to the document using

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

and then there is only the actual function left that would be to blame:

```
function downloadFile(name, url, y,x, canvasid, wrapperid){
   alert(name);
   window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
   function(fileSystem) {
      var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root; // to get root path to directory
      var rootdir = fileSystem.root;
      var fp = rootdir.fullPath;
      fp = fp+"/bestsongs/"+name;
      alert("downloading: " + url + " to " + fp);
      var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
      alert("downloading: " + url + " to " + fp);
      fileTransfer.download(
            url,
            name,
            function(theFile) {
                  alert("download complete: " + theFile.toURI());
                  loadPDF(theFile.toURI(), y,x, canvasid, wrapperid);
      },function(error) {
            alert("error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
      }
   );
   }, 
   function(arg) { 
      alert("FAIL ON requestFileSystem" + JSON.stringify(arg)); }
  );
}

 $(function() {
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
       alert("deviceready!");
       try {
           alert(url);
           downloadFile(lyrics,url,y,x, 'the-canvas', 'wrapper');
       } catch(e) {
           alert(e);
       }
}, false);
});
```

Using the alerts, here is what I get:

```
deviceready!
<url> to file (which is right)
the name of the file.
downloading <url> to //bestsongs/<name>
downloading <url> to //bestsongs/<name>
error: {
        "code":1, 
        "source":<url>, 
        "target":<name>, 
        "http_status": null, 
        "body": null
       }
```

I have been debugging this for days, please someone have the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey take a look at my answer over here -

[Phonegap - Save image from url into device photo gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577230/phonegap-save-image-from-url-into-device-photo-gallery/21579097#21579097)

and let me know. If there is still any problem.
Include following in your config.xml

For Android -

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file" />
<feature name="File">
       <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
</feature>
<feature name="FileTransfer">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer" />
</feature>
<feature name="Storage">
       <param value="org.apache.cordova.Storage" name="android-package"/>
</feature>
```

For IOS-

```
<plugin name="File" value="CDVFile" />
<plugin name="FileTransfer" value="CDVFileTransfer" />
```

For checking network connection available or not add following in your config.xml -
add permissions in plugin.xml and plugins name in config.xml

Plugin to check Network connection
For Android -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager" />
```

For IOS -

```
<plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="CDVConnection" />
```

Comment: Now I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined from var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

Comment: Or you can remove that stuff checking Internet connection availablity if you dont want.

Comment: After doing all that I get `{code: 1, source: "<encoded url>", target: "//<folder>/<filename>", http_status: null, body: null}`. Whats wrong with that?

Comment: use my code for download. i provided link to you already. Its perfect working code for android and IOS. In which you can download any type of file in specific folder. You just have to provide 3 parameters to that. Download link URL, folder name, file name. Refer that answer.

Comment: It really does not work on my droid. And I am using your code (only without the network check) the problem is imho that `rootdir.fullPath` returns `//` on my system.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49400/discussion-between-suhas-and-e2bady)

Comment: @e2bady did you manage to solve this? Is saving file to where your app is located possible?