# Phonegap. Cannot write into app's data folder/directory

Tags: android, cordova

Following my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37277611/how-to-download-a-file-with-phonegap-6-x) it appears that it is not possible to write into the following app's data folders which are identified by:

```
cordova.file.dataDirectory

cordova.file.externalDataDirectory
```

Which are translated respectively into:

```
file:///data/data/my_app_id/files

file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/my_id_app/files/
```

and which both map to the same destination (the internal Android storage space):

```
.../sdcard0/Android/data/my_id_app/files/
```

When the app is installed, inside `.../sdcard0/Android/data/` a directory named `my_id_app` is created with two subdirectories `files` and `cache`. The `files` directory has no write permissions:

- If I try to write into `cordova.file.dataDirectory` no error is
  reported. The operation seems to have been successful but it is
  not. I cannot write into this directory even if the phone is rooted.
- If I try to write into `cordova.file.externalDataDirectory` `error code = 1` (file not found) is raised. Nothing can be written into this directory. I can read/write into this directory only if the phone rooted.

I did these tests on my Samsung S3 Mini (**Android 4.1.2**) and **Phonegap Build 6.2**. Nothing about these kind of permissions restrictions is specified or clearly explained in the official documentation at [cordova-plugin-file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/).

I would like to write into the app's data directory because it's the only directory that it's removed when the user uninstalls the app. I don't want to leave pieces of my app into the user's phone if he wants to remove the app.

**If these directories are not writable where should I save the files the app downloads and be sure they are removed when the app is uninstalled?**

Any thoughts, explanations, suggestions? I'm missing something?

Comment: This is weird, I am using that locations and I am able to write in all of them in all my devices. I haven't have a Samsung, can it be a Samsung Bug? Can you reproduce in another device or simulator?

Comment: @Del. This would be terrible! I will check. What Android version are you using?

Comment: Nexus 6 - 6.0.1 and a Huawei - 5.1.1. Also working on iOS simulator