# Phonegap 3.4 FileTransfer error (iOS)

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to load a file from a server and save it on the device. This code used to work in Phonegap 3.1, and it's still working fine with 3.4 on Android. But when I run the same code on iOS 7.1. I got an error saying,

```
{
    "code":1,
    "source":"http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/18/96730/70400",
    "target":null,
    "http_status":200,
    "body":"Could not create target file"
}
```

Here's my code.

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
fileTransfer.download(encodeURI('http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/18/96730/70400'), '/com.mee.flight/maptile/70400', function (entry) {
    //Do something
});
```

At first I thought the solution is straight forward, since Phonegap actually tells me that there's something wrong with the target file. So, I fiddled with the file path, but they didn't really work out. Any idea?

Comment: refer- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577230/phonegap-save-image-from-url-into-device-photo-gallery/21579097#21579097

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out already. In case anyone's having the same problem, the solution is to use 'cdvfile://localhost/persistent/' to get to the root folder in Phonegap. So, in my case, the change would be,

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
fileTransfer.download(encodeURI('http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/18/96730/70400'), 'cdvfile://localhost/persistent/com.mee.flight/maptile/70400', function (entry) {
    //Do something
});
```

Comment: Could you please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24610313/app-cache-ios-phonegap if you perhaps have any hints