# PhoneGap File Read Write: PhoneGap read write file html code isn't working on android device

Tags: android, cordova, xui

I was trying some cookbook samples of phonegap app(along with xui) to read write files to local storage(SD card), PhoneGap is so popular in its file io, but when I tried on the device it didn't do anything. I think somebody has encountered same things.

The code is shown below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width;" />
    <title>File Download</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="xui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >

    var downloadDirectory;

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        window.requestFileSystem(
            LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 
            0, 
            onFileSystemSuccess, 
            null
        );

        x$('#download_btn').on( 'click', function(e) {
            download();
        });
    }

    function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getDirectory('my_downloads',{create:true},
            function(dir) {
                downloadDirectory = dir;
            },fail);
    }

    function fail(error) {
        x$('#message').html('We encountered a problem: ' + error.code);
    }

    function download() {
        var fileURL = document.getElementById('file_url').value;
        var localFileName = getFilename(fileURL);

        x$('#message').html('Downloading ' + localFileName);

        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        fileTransfer.download(fileURL, downloadDirectory.fullPath + '/' + localFileName, 
            function(entry){
                x$('#message').html('Download complete. File saved to: ' + entry.fullPath);
            }, 
            function(error){
                alert("Download error source " + error.source);
            }
        );
    }

    // Obtain the filename
    function getFilename(url) {
       if (url) {
          var m = url.toString().match(/.*\/(.+?)\./);
          if (m && m.length > 1) {
             return m[1] + '.' + url.split('.').pop();
          }
       }
       return "";
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="text"      id="file_url"       value="http://blogs.adobe.com/adobeingovernment/files/2012/07/phonegap.jpg" />
    <input type="button"    id="download_btn"   value="Download" />

    <div id="message"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I already reviewed android manifest file, it has all permission including write to external storage. Kindly advise.

Comment: Refer- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577230/phonegap-save-image-from-url-into-device-photo-gallery/21579097#21579097