# How to save an Image object into a file in Android with Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Here's the thing, I generate a PNG image in the application and I get an Image object with JavaScript, something like this...

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + base64Img;
```

I want to save that image to the internal storage. Is there a plugin or a way I can do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577230/phonegap-save-image-from-url-into-device-photo-gallery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577230/phonegap-save-image-from-url-into-device-photo-gallery):

This is file download code which can be used by anyone. You just have three parameters to use this like-

1) **URL**

2) **Folder name** which you want to create in your Sdcard

3) **File name** (You can give any name to file)

All types of file can download by using this code. you can use this as .js
And this works on `IOS` also.

- First step check parameters mismatch and checking network connection if available call    download function
- Second step to get Write permission and Folder Creation
- Third step for download a file into created folder

Also check [this link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#File)

Answer (score 0):

```
 function onPhotoDataSuccess1(imageData) { 
        alert(imageData);
        sessionStorage.setItem("img_api",imageData);
        $('#largeImage').attr('src','data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData);
    }
```

Hope, it will helps you!