# How can I easily download a text file on android using javascript and cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, download

I'm struggling to download a simple text generated by cordova app to device. It is simple in browser, but I can't make it work on Android (see [Cordova file plugin not working when I try to download img on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73997358/cordova-file-plugin-not-working-when-i-try-to-download-img-on-android)).
Is there an easier way to save file on disk? Or maybe get access to database?

I am at my whit's end.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with the [File plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html), but there are a few moving parts to get it working properly:

1. You need to write to a sandboxed directory (either `cordova.file.externalDataDirectory` or `cordova.file.dataDirectory`), as of Android 10/11.
2. You need to add `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to your `config.xml` (to add to your Android app's `manifest.xml`)
3. You need to have the appropriate runtime permission as well if you're accessing external storage.

(see [How to get documents in an android directory that PhoneGap will see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678186/how-to-get-documents-in-an-android-directory-that-phonegap-will-see/29905718#29905718) for code snippets)

4. Having done that, you'll be working with the FileWriter to write the text to a Blob.

If you need a leg up, you can take a look at my app (I've got a text writer at about line 3239 of this file: https://github.com/adapt-it/adapt-it-mobile/blob/master/www/js/views/DocumentViews.js). It also handles copying the text to the clipboard using the `Cordova-clipboard` plugin, which might be of use.