# Cordova - Save image from url into device photo gallery

Tags: cordova, mobile

I am developing an application with **Apache Cordova** that downloads and saves images, but I can not save and display the Gallery, the image goes to `file:///data/data` for while i'm trying to run on Android, what can I do?

My code:

```js
 function download(URL, Folder_Name, File_Name) {
        //step to request a file system 
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, fileSystemSuccess, fileSystemFail);

        function fileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
            var download_link = encodeURI(URL);
            var ext = download_link.substring(download_link.lastIndexOf('.') + 1); //Get extension of URL
            var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root; // to get root path of directory
            directoryEntry.getDirectory(Folder_Name, { create: true, exclusive: false }, onDirectorySuccess, onDirectoryFail); // creating folder in sdcard
            var rootdir = fileSystem.root;
            var fp = rootdir.toURL(); // Returns Fulpath of local directory
            console.log(rootdir);
            fp = fp + "/" + Folder_Name + "/" + File_Name; // fullpath and name of the file which we want to give
            // download function call                
            filetransfer(download_link, fp);
        }

        function onDirectorySuccess(parent) {
            //alert("Sucesso");
        }

        function onDirectoryFail(error) {
            //Error while creating directory
            alert("Unable to create new directory: " + error.code);
        }

        function fileSystemFail(evt) {
            //Unable to access file system
            alert(evt.target.error.code);
        }
    }

    function filetransfer(download_link, fp) {
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        console.log(fp);
        // File download function with URL and local path
        fileTransfer.download(download_link, fp,
                            function (entry) {
                                //alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
                            },
                         function (error) {
                             //Download abort errors or download failed errors
                             console.log(error);
                             alert(error.exception);
                             alert("download error source " + error.source);
                             //alert("download error target " + error.target);
                             //alert("upload error code" + error.code);
                         }
                    );
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Phonegap - Save image from url into device photo gallery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577230/phonegap-save-image-from-url-into-device-photo-gallery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images were being saved, but needed the [Media Scanner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html) to index the images on gallery

**Media Scanner:**

> MediaScannerConnection provides a way for applications to pass a newly
>   created or downloaded media file to the media scanner service. The
>   media scanner service will read metadata from the file and add the
>   file to the media content provider.

How was working with Apache Cordova / PhoneGap it provides no native method to refresh the images in the native gallery, I had to just look for a plugin to do this job. The plugins I found were:

[cordova-mediascanner-plugin](https://github.com/Xul13/cordova-mediascanner-plugin)
[MediaScannerPlugin](https://github.com/peteygao/MediaScannerPlugin/)

Both have a basic documentation, however i used **cordova-mediascanner-plugin**.

By implementing this plugin, just modified my `filetransfer` method

```
function filetransfer(download_link, fp) {
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        console.log(fp);

        // File download function with URL and local path
        fileTransfer.download(download_link, fp,
                            function (entry) {
                                //alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
                                window.plugins.scanmedia.scanFile(fp, function (msg) {
                                    alert("Success ScanMedia");
                                }, function (err) {
                                    alert("Fail ScanMedia: " + err);
                                })
                            },
                         function (error) {
                             //Download abort errors or download failed errors
                             console.log(error);
                             alert(error.exception);
                             alert("download error source " + error.source);
                             //alert("download error target " + error.target);
                             //alert("upload error code" + error.code);
                      }
                    );

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

please try to import this plugin in your project :-

https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin.git