# cordova : How to download canvas as image in mobile app?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, canvas

I am developing android app with cordova. I generate dynamic QR Code in canvas with [this](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/jquery-qrcode) lib. When I try to download the QR code It works fine in browser. But when I try to download to gallery it doesnt download and no console logs.

HTML:

```
<a id="downlodQrCode"> Download Now </a>
```

JS:

```
$('#downlodQrCode').click(function(){
   var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0],
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    downloadCanvas = function(link, canvasId, filename) {
      link.href = document.getElementsByTagName(canvasId)[0].toDataURL('image/jpeg');
      link.download = filename;
    }

    downloadCanvas( document.getElementById('downlodQrCode') , 'canvas', 'test.jpeg' );
});
```

How to download image from cordova app?

Comment: Are you using download attribute of anchor HTML tag for this?

Comment: @Akki619 Yes, its anchor tag

Comment: I think android web view does not support download attribute. I would suggest to look for another option using cordova; they have provision for this.

Comment: @Akki619. Please checkout my edited question

Comment: I don't think it will save to gallery automatically; from my POV, file needs to be placed in gallery manually. Cordova have provision for this. File System access and file writing,

Comment: Thanks @Akki619, Let me try file system access

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577230/phonegap-save-image-from-url-into-device-photo-gallery ; this might help you; instead of url u have base 64 of image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86776/discussion-between-akki619-and-blue-bells).