# Is it possible to download new images in PhoneGap and store them on device

Tags: android, ios, cordova

Apologies if this is a simple question, but I have never used PhoneGap.

If I wrapped a html site in a web frame as a phone gap app, is it possible to sync the app with a web service, download new images and store them permanently in local storage for use in the app?

Id like to be able to update some elements without a new version of the app needing release.

Currently device agnostic but this could be a deciding factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, possible. And there is another similar question. Please check this:

[Phonegap - Save image from url into device photo gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577230/phonegap-save-image-from-url-into-device-photo-gallery)

Comment: Thanks, just what I wanted to hear