# Save image into Gallery (Camera roll) Ionic 2

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I save image from server to local path on device

```
downLoad() {
    this.http.downloadFile('http://example.com/files/files/image.jpg', {}, {}, 'image.jpg')
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data) ;
    })
    .catch(error => {

        console.log(error) ;

    });

}
```

But image save not in Photo Gallery. How it fix?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Phonegap - Save image from url into device photo gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577230/phonegap-save-image-from-url-into-device-photo-gallery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with this plugin: https://github.com/terikon/cordova-plugin-photo-library

After adding the plugin, you can save pictures like that:

```
var url = 'file:///...'; // file or remote URL. url can also be dataURL, but giving it a file path is much faster
var album = 'MyAppName';
cordova.plugins.photoLibrary.saveImage(url, album, function (libraryItem) {}, function (err) {});
```

Comment: var album = 'MyAppName'; If that album 'MyAppName' not in the device ,then will it really work ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the album will be created if it doesn't exist.